# JS/JQuery switch not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know why it's working:

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

if(keycode == '13')
{
    key_click("ent");    
}
});
```

but it's not working:

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

switch(keycode)
{
    case '13': key_click("ent"); break;
}
});
```

I need switch because i want to add more options in switch.

Comment: `keycode` is Number. `case '13'` will not match.

Comment: FYI, jQuery has normalized long time ago (v. 1.1.3) which key code is pressed, you should just use `event.which;`

Answer (score 2):

Since the keycode is the number type not string type,

In your if condition:

```
if(keycode == '13') // not checked with strict equality operator so it works
```

But in your switch:

```
case '13': // switch case checks with strict equality so it won't work.
```

You need to use:

```
case 13:
```

Answer (score 1):

do this

```
switch(keycode)
{
    case 13: key_click("ent"); break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To demonstrate, this works:

```
if(keycode == '13')
{
    key_click("ent");    
}
```

But *this* doesn't:

```
if(keycode === '13')
{
    key_click("ent");    
}
```

Notice the difference in the operator used.  JavaScript isn't strict about types when comparing with `==`, so `13 == '13'` is `true`.  However, the `===` operator *is* strict about types, so `13 === '13'` is `false`.

The `switch` operator is also strict.  Simply use the same type for the comparison:

```
switch(keycode)
{
    case 13: key_click("ent"); break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change :

```
case '13':
```

To :

```
case 13:
```

Answer (score 0):

If Your input is string then you could use following :

```js
var keycode = "13";
switch(keycode)
{
    case '13' : console.log("case 13"); break;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```